# What is the fastest way to find the range of functions having modulus: $f(x) = |x+3| - |x+1| - |x-1| + |x-3|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

While solving problems I saw a question in which I was supposed to find the range of a function $$f(x) = |x+3| - |x+1| - |x-1| + |x-3|$$ I know the way in which I can take different cases of $x$ larger than $3$ and then $x$ between $3$ and $1$ and so on. But it gets a bit long as there are 5 cases and the competitive exam for which I am getting my brain ready for wants me to solve a question in average 1.5 minutes. I want to know if there exists a faster way to find its range.

Comment: There is no particular technical.

Comment: @Surb I know that there are many ways to find the range but what is faster than the way i described in my question.

Comment: I think it's the best way to do it (and I don't see an other way here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us have a look at the two parts of your function. What is $|x-3|-|x-1|$? This is the distance of $x$ from $3$ minus the distance of $x$ from $1$. Can we say what this function looks like? If $x$ is on the right of the interval $[1,3]$, then the difference is obviously $-2$. If $x$ is on the left then the difference is clearly $2$. In the interval $[1,3]$ this function changes linearly between the two values.

The following graph is [taken from WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Cx-3%7C-%7Cx-1%7C), but if you have seen a few such functions and you keep the above interpretation (absolute value as distance) in mind, you should be able to plot this graph easily by hand.

[image]

In the same way we can plot $|x+3|-|x+1|$  which looks rather similar. And you want to add these two functions together. You can simply plot both of them [into the same graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5B%7Cx-3%7C-%7Cx-1%7C%2C+%7Cx%2B3%7C-%7Cx%2B1%7C%5D).

[image]

- You can see that for $x<-3$ and for $x>3$, one of the values is $2$ and the other one is $-2$. So the sum will be zero.
- On the interval $(-1,1)$ both functions have value $2$, so their sum will be $4$.
- In the two intervals inbetween the functions changes linearly, since it is a sum of two linear functions.

Here is a [plot from WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Cx-3%7C-%7Cx-1%7C%2B%7Cx%2B3%7C-%7Cx%2B1%7C). But again you should be able to sketch the graph of this function by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x) = |x+3| + |x-3|$ and $h(x) = |x+1| + |x-1|.$
Then
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \begin{cases} 2|x| & \text{if $|x| \geq 3$} \\
                    6 & \text{if $|x| < 3$} \end{cases} \\
h(x) &= \begin{cases} 2|x| & \text{if $|x| \geq 1$} \\
                    2 & \text{if $|x| < 1$} \end{cases} \\
f(x) &= g(x) - h(x)
\end{align}
It should then be easy to see that $f(x) = 0$ when $|x| \geq 3$
and $f(x) = 4$ when $|x| < 1$.
You just then have to confirm that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 4$
when $1 \leq |x| < 3$.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, one short-cut you could use is to notice that the function is **even**, so to cut down on the work you would only need to consider the set $x\geq0$ to establish the range for the whole function.